# regular expression evaluation in string matching

Tags: regex, string

I am reading Regular expression in Algorithms by Robert Sedgwick book.

Here for regular expression mention below

```
A* | (A*BA*BA*)*
```

Here author mentioned matches are: AAA, BBAABB, and  BABAAA.
does not match for above regular expression are ABA BBB BABBAAA.

My question is how BBAABB is matching and same way how BABAAA is matching. Kindly explain.

In general I am looking for how to evaluate with | and * operators in regular expressions.
in below example how we can get b alone in set if we have a+ since it says we must have atleast 1 a.

```
(a+b)* = (λ, a, b, aa, ab, ba, bb, aaa, ...)
```

Comment: Try it at regex101.com. You will see that the 2nd branch can match `BB` (and `ABAB`, `BAB`, `BABA`, `ABBA`, `ABABA`, etc.)  or nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one difference between `*` and `+`. The character after which you put `*` can have no repetition. But in `+` case, it can have minimum 1 repetition.
In `A* | (A*BA*BA*)*`, `BBAABB` is valid for following reasons and it is according to `(A*BA*BA*)*` pattern

1. No `A` at start for `A*`
2. 1 B for `BA*` and no `A`
3. 1 B for `BA*` and 2 A
4. `*` at end of `(A*BA*BA*)*`shows that pattern can repeat. So second repetition is `BB` which is valid

These are the points for which `BBAABB` is valid.